# Как удалить элементы без изменения списка?

Tags: python

Нужно удалить три max-элемента из списка, причём нельзя изменять список. Как сделать тут копию этого списка(правильно) и удалить с конца списка и вернуться к нужному виду?

```
elements = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 9, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22]
elements_copy = elements.copy()
 
for _ in range(3):
    elements_copy.remove(max(elements_copy))
 
print(elements, elements_copy, sep="\n")
```

Как это сделать БЕЗ циклов, с использованием функции? (чтобы список не изменялся, надо работать с копией списка, а потом вернуться к нормальному виду)

Comment: Вопрос противоречит сам себе: удаление элемента из списка автоматически является изменением списка. Так что то, что вы хотите, осуществить невозможно

Comment: Можно работать с копией и вернуться к начальному

Comment: Если работать с копией, то это получается создание нового списка без лишних элементов, а не удаление элементов

Comment: Если гарантируется, что исходный список отсортирован, то можно просто сделать elements[:-3]

Answer (score 1):

> Как это сделать БЕЗ циклов, с использованием функции?

Можно реализовать рекурсию:

```py
def f(li, n=3):
    if n == 0:
        return li

    li.remove(max(li))
    return f(li, n-1)
```

Comment: `li.remove` является изменением списка, что запрещено условием задачи

Comment: @andreymal Я предполагал, что автор передаст копию. Так же, как делает в своём коде.

Comment: Создание копии списка означает отсутствие удаления из исходного списка, что тоже противоречит условию задачи :)

Comment: А вообще если копии это нормально и filter подходит под условие «без циклов», то можно упороться в функциональщину и сделать что-то вроде `li = list(filter(lambda x: x != max(li), li))` (при условии неповторяющихся элементов)

Comment: @andreymal Но придётся исхитриться, чтобы делать это `n` раз без циклов. Можно оберуть в ещё одну `lambda`, например. Думаю, стоит дождаться от автора более корректного объяснения того, что же он всё-таки хочет :)

Comment: Нужно сделать это именно с копией списка, без сортировки тоже никак походу. А потом вернуться к начальному списку

Comment: @Rintys Что значит _"вернуться к начальному списку"_? Если Вы делаете копию — у Вас 2 разных списка.

Answer (score 0):

Если вдруг я правильно сумел понять задачу, то вот так:

```
elements = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 9, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22]
elements_copy = list(filter(lambda x: x not in sorted(elements)[-3:], elements))
print(elements, elements_copy, sep="\n")
```

Вывод:

```
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 9, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 9, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19]
```

В копию списка попадают все элементы кроме трёх максимальных, которые мы отобрали, взяв последние 3 элемента отсортированного во возрастанию списка. Для подобной фильтрации итерируемых объектов в Python есть специальная функция `filter`.

P.S. Реализация в виде отдельной функции по просьбе автора вопроса:

```
def filter3max(elements):
    return list(filter(lambda x: x not in sorted(elements)[-3:], elements))

elements = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 9, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22]
print(elements, filter3max(elements), sep="\n")
```

Comment: @andreymal Я как-раз делал вообще без for в этот момент, вот заменил ))

Comment: а как это в функции реализовать?

Comment: @Rintys Дополнил ответ, если я опять же правильно понял